# Unable to Run Nvidia Settings

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, resolution

I am using Dell Latitude E6510 laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 running on it.
It has Nvidia GT218 NVS 3100M.
I am using `Gnome-Fallback` mode.

My problem is that my laptop was just working fine.
However, it was having very high temperatures (+70 degrees normally). 
So I read about some blogs, where someone advised to install `Jupiter` and `nvidia-bumblebee`. So I installed these 2 softwares.

However, with `Jupiter`, I was unable to change the screen resolution.
Neither it was able to detect the external monitor. 
Though my laptop was super-cool. It was running at 50-60 degrees. 
But since this being useless, as I always use an external monitor, I uninstalled both the softwares. Also I realised that I don't have `Optimus` support on my laptop.

Now I am unable to go back to the initial settings. I am stuck up at 800 x 600 resolution. 
When I try to run nvidia-settings I get an error message saying:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server
```

I tried to run `nvidia-xconfig`, but it didn't work. The error remains the same.

I tried to find help on internet on lot of forums.
I tried to re-install the nvidia packages, but it didn't work.
Also I tried to use nouveau driver, and then again install nvidia drivers, the problem is still the same.

Could someone please let me know how do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following commands to remove bumblebee completely and it worked !

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```